# Can't find the mixer in the new version of TuxGuitar (v1.3.2)

Tags: guitar, tablature, mixer, tuxguitar

I just downloaded the new version of TuxGuitar and when I went to play one of my songs the levels of each track were all off.  The drums are far too loud and the guitar is barely audible.  The problem is, with the new version of TuxGuitar the mixer seems to have disappeared!

(The mixer lets you control the volume of each track.)

How can I get to the mixer in the new version of TuxGuitar?!?

I feel like I have to be missing something silly... they wouldn't just remove such an important feature.... would they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this on [the SourceForge forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/tuxguitar/discussion/522984/thread/59066f2d/?limit=25#a2d6).  Click on the guitar icon on the toolbar and choose "Show Instruments":

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ahhh, I actually looked at that but couldn't see where the volume was adjusted.  I didn't realize you had to click on the little "V" near each instrument.  Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Where's the darn "V"? I open that dialog but I can't see any "V"... (at least in OSX, I don't know if it's an issue only in Mac)

Comment: How do you actually use the dropdown from the V button? It only lets me set values to 127 or 27

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see the "V", but I found out 6 circles at the right of each instrument. Volume can be tuned with the first one.

Comment: Could you add some more explicit description/instruction to this? That would make it a stronger answer. Perhaps a screen-shot?

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the 6 circles, it tells you what they are. here it is from left to right. Volume, Balance, Reverb, Chorus, Tremolo, Phaser.