# Can you change the volume of a specific track in TuxGuitar 1.3?

Tags: tablature, tuxguitar

In old TuxGuitar versions, you could open the Mixer and adjust the volume for each track on it's own. In the current Windows version (1.3.2) the Mixer has been replaced with the "Instruments" dialog, which lacks such a feature.

Is there a new way to change to volumes of each track, or is that gone?

Answer (score 3):

As answered in [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44381/cant-find-the-mixer-in-the-new-version-of-tuxguitar-v1-3-2) , you need to click on the "V" button, which is available for each instrument in the "Instruments" dialog.

Comment: How do you actually change the volume there? I can only get it to set to 127 or 27.