# Does anyone here use TuxGuitar and is by chance able to tell me how to adjust the volume of tracks seperately?

Tags: tuxguitar

As stated in title I can not find any way to adjust the volume of each instrument in the instrument tabs.
I would be quite delighted if someone could provide me with a way to do this.
If you know how do this it would be very kind if you could provide me with a screenshot of your menu and point out the corresponding unit to change the volume.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you change the volume of a specific track in TuxGuitar 1.3?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/can-you-change-the-volume-of-a-specific-track-in-tuxguitar-1-3)

Comment: Not really, i saw that post as well but i can't find the mentioned v anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some knobs in the instrument settings. The first one controls the volume:

[image: Knobs in the instrument settings]

I added the red arrow, which points to the knob that controls the volume. Note that this setting affects the volume of an instrument. If several tracks are associated with the same instrument, this knob controls the volume of all of them. So this is not quite the same as controlling the volume on a per-track level. If you want to achieve this, I think that you need to create an instrument for each track.